# Partial import or the Maven existing project in Eclipse Version 2021-03 (4.19.0)

Tags: eclipse, maven, project

I don't understand the behaviour of Eclipse and Maven.

**Context**

I'm studiyng Vert.x and I'm analyzing this project in [marcorotondi github](https://github.com/marcorotondi/Vert.x).

1. I run *git clone* in my workspace by Git shell.
2. In the filesystem, there are 4 dir and every dir has his **pom.xml**.
3. I run Eclipse.
4. I run *File>Import>Maven>Existing Maven Project*.
5. I check all the 4 Projects and click the "*Finish*" button.

**What I expect to find**

I expect to find all the 4 project in my workspace

**What I find**

I see only 2 projects, the first and last project in alphabetic order (I attach the screen) [image: my workspace after git clone]

If I try to import again the other project, the dialog window shows me the message (I attach the screen)
[image: incomplete import in my workspace]

> Project DemoVertx already exists, add a version of custom suffix using
> "Name Template" in "Advanced" settings".

Furthermore, I see that in first screenshot the project DemoVertX has the strings
[Vertx master], that is linked to current GIT branch after a clone
(in first), where first is a name of a subdir of the project, but I don't see any parent pom of the project, then the project is not multi-module.

Please, can you give me some explications (or some references)  about this?
How I can to import all the 4 projects in the same time?

Thank you a lot

Comment: I would strongly recommend to take a look here: https://vertx.io/ instead....

Comment: It looks that the import resolves all to the same project name `DemoVertx` and project name must be unique. Does renaming the imported project and then importing the next project work?

Comment: Hi @howlger , you're right! I runned grep and I found <groupId>com.marco</groupId<artifactId>DemoVertX</artifactId><version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>! Thank yo uvery much. It's first time that I see more projects with the ame groupId-artifactId-version, sincerly I would expected a different behavior by Eclipse. Thank again!

Comment: You might contribute the different behavior to [Eclipse m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git itself: it looks like a glitch with Eclipse-the-IDE and its naming conventions. Note that Git does not use POM files: they're just ordinary files, to Git. (The fact that they contain XML will cause headaches later if you try to use Git to manage them, because Git doesn't understand XML in any real sense.)

Comment: Hi @torek, I agree with you: I talked about GIT only because I see the (in first, in secont, in third) indication is near the name of the branch, but my hypothesis were about Maven. I read the three pom.xml, but I was concentrate only about pom-parent hyp and I did'nt see the simplest cause (three artifacts with same groupId-artifactId-version)